# Change content in DIV based on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found this script, that i want to implement into my webside.

http://codepen.io/johnmotyljr/pen/qhvue

It does exactly what i want it to do, BUT! I don't know how to put into my webside?! Where to put the JS and how?

The content that i need to change is stored in an html-file, but how do i get that content into my div with this script?

Hope you can understand what i'm asking for and sorry for my limited/bad english!

Comment: what is your site currently built with e.g. HTML, PHP, .NET? Is it a CMS i.e. Wordpress / Joomla or is it plain HTML

Comment: I'm writing in dhtml :)

Comment: Can we see the code/markup of the page that you want this functionality on?

Comment: [link](http://simonhollander.dk/v/cash.shtml) - Still some small things that bugs me on the site, but under the right column saying "Volstrups Cash", there's four links, which should change the content directly under.

Answer (score 0):

You can load that content via AJAX. So, building on the CodePen-example you gave, you could do something like this:

```
$('#kittens').click(function() {
    $('div').load('kittens.html');
});
```

Where `kittens.html` is the URL of the html file you want to load.

**Update:**

Now that you have posted a link to your website, I notice a few more things:

- You haven't got jQuery included. Between you `<head></head>` tags you
  should include `<script type="text/javascript"
  src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`
- Probably, you want the `Resultater | Billeder | Video | Afkom` links to load different content, right? Then, you should use
  something like this:

In between `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`:

```
$('.hesteundertop a[href="#resul"]').click(function(e) {
    $('.hestetekst').load('... Resultater URL ...');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: So an URL could be 'content/kittens.html'?
But how do i put this into my page?

Comment: Yes, you could use that URL. You could put it anywhere on your page, preferably in a `document.ready(function(){ ... })` closure (that will make sure jQuery and the DOM is available).
Also make sure that jQuery is included on your page. And (probably) you have more than 1 div, so the `$('div')` selector should be more specific. Finally, you should have an element with the id `kittens` for the `$('#kittens')` selector to work.

Comment: Thx for the replies! I can't figure out how to tell the script to work when clicking the link, e.g. "Resultater"?

Comment: Why did you put ".hesteundertop a:nth-child(2)" insted of "#kittens"?

Comment: I simplified my update a bit, so I can explain it better. The $-sign lets me select any element by a CSS-selector using jQuery. So, `$('.hesteundertop a[href="#resul"]')` will refer to an `a`-element, having '#resul' in the `href`-attribute and the element should be a child of `.hesteundertop` (which is a div with the class 'hesteundertop'). Then I tell jQuery to add a click event handler. The code in the handler will fire when you click the link.

Comment: Thx a bunch for the explanation! This all makes sense now! But, how do i put this code into my page? I know nothing about this kind of coding. I think i have to make a *.js file with this code, but are there a way i can put this on the actual page, though i have to use this script on several pages, but this different content.

Comment: Safeer N, got me the answer! :) Are there a way i can make a default start-text?

Comment: Now i have implemented your script, but i cant make it work? I have updated my page [testpage](http://simonhollander.dk/v/cash.shtml), but it won't work..

Comment: @SimonJensen, you're still missing this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`. You should put in the head-part of your HTML. **Above** the other script-tag. By the way, if you are using the ID-attribute, you can shorten the selector to just: `$("#omcash")` :). Furthermore, you're missing `/v` and you are not escaping the space character in your URL: `/heste/Volstrups Cash/html/cashtekst.html` should be `/v/heste/Volstrups%20Cash/html/cashtekst.html`

Comment: Thx for your answer, but either i'm missing something or i close to stupid, but i really can't make it work?!?! I have updated my [testpage](http://simonhollander.dk/v/cash.shtml) again. The "/v/" shouldn't be in the filepath, though "/v/" is the root for the testpage?

Comment: Sidequestion: What to do with long filepaths? This "/heste/Volstrups%20Cash/html/cashstamtavle.html" seems to long to work, but this "includes/cashtekst.html" works. Why?! :S

Answer (score 0):

View the source code of your link, find the `<iframe>` tab, and the demo html is inside.

Answer (score 0):

try this type of method.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var kittens = "Kittens";
            var puppies = "puppies";
            var aardvark = "aardvark";
            $('#kittens').click(function(){
                $('div').html(kittens);
                //$('div').load('kittens.html');
            });
        })
    </script>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li id="kittens"></li>
            <li id="puppies"></li>
            <li id="aardvark"></li>
        </ul>
        <div>Click on the picture for description.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```